# Mutual include breaks types

Tags: objective-c, oop, header-files

I have two classes, Entity, and EntityHandler.

EntityHandler has a method, AddEntity. This method adds the Entity to an NSMutableArray.

Entity has a method called subscribe. It assigns a reference to EntityHandler to a variable for later usage.

Upon the inclusion of both header files in each other the project breaks. For example,

```
-(void) addEntity: (Entity *) mob;
```

returns the error

```
Expected a type
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The syntax doesn't look correct for C++.  Did you tag this correctly?

Comment: The syntax you're using is pretty obviously Objective-C, not C++. I've removed the C++ tag.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking to employ **forward declarations** for your ObjC types, in order to break the cyclic header dependency.

It would look something like:

```
// EntityHandler.h

@class Entity; // << the forward declaration. not #import.

@interface EntityHandler : NSObject
-(void) addEntity:(Entity *) mob;
@end
```

This tells the compiler that there is an ObjC class named `Entity`.

Then you `#import` when you need more than a typename (likely in `EntityHandler.m`).